# Is there something wrong with this code?

Tags: jquery

For some reason, the 'continue' class isn't getting added (last line).

```
function getBlogs(element, url, limit, feed){
    jQuery(element).load(url+ ' .xg_blog_list .xg_module_body:lt('+ limit+ ')', function(){
        jQuery(this).prepend("<a class='home-rss' href='"+ feed+ "'></a>");
        jQuery(this).append("<a class='view-all-blogs' href='"+ url+"'>View More &raquo;</a>");
        jQuery(".xg_module_body .postbody").last("a").each(function(index) {
            addClass("continue");
        });
    });
}
```

Relevant html:

```
<div class="postbody">
     <p><a href="link"><img src="image"></a></p>
     <p>title</p>
     <a href="link">Continue</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What would it add it to?

Comment: There's no need for the `each`, you can just tag the `addClass(...)` onto the `last("a")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `.addClass` on an object, otherwise what would it add the class to?

```
$(this).addClass('continue');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either call:

```
jQuery(".xg_module_body .postbody").last("a").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("continue");
});
```

Or:

```
jQuery(".xg_module_body .postbody").last("a").addClass("continue");
```